# Firebase: Retrieving Data from Another Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I've got two objects in Firebase, and I'm trying to retrieve a url from the `users` object, by matching its key with the `user` value in my `messages` object.

My data looks like this:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "-JmY3zLmz9_6MjLRJCch" : {
      "message" : "test",
      "published" : 1428665136553,
      "user" : "twitter:14075704",
      "username" : "realph"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "twitter:14075704" : {
      "pic" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1180195102/23684_378330977259_680962259_4275328_5191_n_normal.jpg"
    },
    "twitter:86584100" : {
      "pic" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000196615428/dfb3b5fbdc1a260cea977dc3f24262ab_normal.jpeg"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to match the `messages.user` with the `users.key()` so I can retrieve the `pic` value.

**app.js**

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/");
var messagesRef = ref.child('messages');
var usersRef = ref.child('users');
var currentUser = null;

messagesRef.orderByChild("published").on('child_added', function(snap) {
  $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(messagesRef);
  $scope.users = $firebaseArray(usersRef);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
  {{ message.username }}
  {{ message.message }}
  {{ message.user }}
  <img ng-src="IMAGE TO GO HERE" />
</div>
```

What's the easiest and best way to go about doing this? I'm stumped at the moment.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since `users` is an object (it looks like a dictionary keyed by userId) just check the property.  You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to get the property of an object with a string variable.  This is really great for objects with your dictionary-like setup since the property names are the keys for the dictionary.

Most simply, a function to turn a `user` string into its image src would look like this:

```
$scope.getImage = function (user) {
    var users = $scope.users;
    if (users[user] != null) { //check if the property exists
        return users[user].pic;
    }
    return "No user found";
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    Image src: {{ getImage(message.user)}}
    <img ng-src="{{getImage(message.user)}}" />
</div>
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IlQEKgwpwdSrr7f56J9k?p=preview)

Comment: This is great, but it keeps returning "No user found".  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Something tells me I'm not able to expose `pic` as I'm not extracting the Firebase snapshot...

Comment: That's weird.  It's possible that the property does actually exist but is "empty".  Perhaps changing to `if (users[user])` would help.  If not, you'll have to do some more debugging and figure out what your `$scope.users` and `user` look like when the function is called.